# Is there a way to set a certain start time hour/minutes for a sprint?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I would like to set a more precise time for starting the sprint in DevOps, currently it allows only dates to be configured.

Comment: No. Why do you want to do that? It's uncommon for that to matter; sprints typically start and end at the start and end of business days.

Comment: So for e.g. in my sprint there are some unfinished User Stories. If I move them in the next sprint before the sprint ends, the burn-down shows that sprint scope is 100% met which is not accurate.  If I move the US in the day with the new sprint, they are reflected as scope change in the new sprint burn-down. So  I would have wanted to have some hours in which I can do the changes... and have accurate burndown. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @coconut would you please put your reasoning / previous comment also into the question - so to have a concise question. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set a certain start time hour/minutes for a sprint?

For this issue , as Daniel mentioned in the comment, currently azure devops does not support setting the time accurate to the hour/minute for the spirit.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. Don't move your US across sprints. If you have created tasks for the US or work has started on any tasks in the US from previous sprints, then leave the US in the previous sprint and move the tasks over.
That way you can track which stories are incomplete at the end of each sprint and understand your actual velocity more easily.
The danger of moving unfinished work over is that you may have 90% finished a large story and give yourself a false image of success in your current sprint, affecting future estimations.